# Validate consecutive Doubleletters in WIndows phone

Tags: c#, .net, regex, windows-phone-8.1

My  requirement  is,
Two consecutive  double  letters to  be  allowed .if  user  types third consecutive  letter ,It has  to  show  validation  error.

```
    **Ex-words  like  "aabbcc"  should  be  blocked.**
```

I  started to use  Regex  class..

```
 Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"content/([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)");
```

I'm not   sure  how  to  proceed.

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex.Match(input, @"(?:([A-Za-z0-9\-])\1){3}")
```

The `\1` will match the first tag = first character, so the stuff inside the `(?:` basically says - look for a double character. We then suffix that with `{3}` which says *do this 3 times*.

So, if `match.Success` is `true`, you have 3 consecutive doubles in the input.

If you want to extend the search for triple or quadruple letters, you suffix the `\1` with a `{2}` (for triple test) or `{3}` for quadruple test:

- `@"(?:([A-Za-z0-9\-])\1{2}){3}"` - triple test
- `@"(?:([A-Za-z0-9\-])\1{3}){3}"` - quadruple test

An excellent resource for testing regex patterns is: [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: how  to  implement "aaabbbccc"..can  you  suggest any  link to  learn  regex  completely.

Comment: May I suggest `@"(?:([A-Za-z0-9\-])\1+){3}"` to catch any number of repeated characters? Or even `@"(?:([A-Za-z0-9\-])\1+.*){3}"`, which also catches "aaaabcccccdeeeee" (repeats, optionally separated by non-repeats)